# Scriptural basis for Ramakrishna's claim about 'inner nerve of memory' (medhā nāḍī)

Tags: identification-request, upanishads, yoga, ramakrishna, brahmacharya

In [The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna / Volume 1 / Rules for Householders and Monks](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/gospel/volume_1/20_rules.htm), Ramakrishna Paramahansa makes the following claim.

> MAHIMA:
>
> > Sir, why does a man become deluded by worldly objects?
>
> MASTER:
>
> > It is because he lives in their midst without having realized
> >     God. Man never succumbs to delusion after he has realized God. The
> >     moth no longer enjoys darkness if it has once seen the light.
> >
> > To be able to realize God, one must practise absolute continence.
> >     Sages like Sukadeva are examples of an urdhareta. (A man of unbroken
> >     and complete continence.) Their chastity was absolutely unbroken.
> >     There is another class, who previously have had discharges of semen
> >     but who later on have controlled them. **A man controlling the seminal
> >     fluid for twelve years develops a special power. He grows a new inner
> >     nerve called the nerve of memory. Through that nerve he remembers all,
> >     he understands all.**
> >
> > ...

(By 'nerve of memory' he probably means medhā nāḍī)

Is the claim (marked in bold) backed by scriptures?

Also, is he talking about a visible nerve (that which can be observed under a microscope) or an invisible one on the spiritual plane?

Comment: Urdhvaret is here translated as unbroken and complete continence. Which is wrong according to me. If I understand correctly it literally means "the one with an upward semen flow". Urdhwa means up, retas means semen.

You will not get the nadi if you just don't ejaculate. Through some yogic process you will have to transport it to along the spine(f I understand correctly) to the back of brain, where it gets transformed into something else, and accelerates ojas. The claim is if you do this for 12 years it will result in the nadi.

Comment: Even Swami Rama has spoken about this